# How to add waypoints to this progress bar?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, progress-bar, jquery-waypoints

How can I add Waypoints to this progress bar? By this code, it just animates while I need to animate it when the user scrolls. I am also using waypoints but don't know how to integrate it into this snippet.
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){

```
jQuery('.skillbar').each(function(){
    jQuery(this).find('.skillbar-bar').animate({
        width:jQuery(this).attr('data-percent')
    },6000);

});
```

});

Answer (score 1):

**Try this code**

```
$(document).ready(function( ){
        var waypoint = new Waypoint({
              element: document.getElementById('mycontainer'),//Id of container
              handler: function(direction) {
                ProgressBar();
              }
        });

        function ProgressBar(){
            jQuery('.skillbar').each(function(){
                jQuery(this).find('.skillbar-bar').animate({
                    width:jQuery(this).attr('data-percent')
                },6000);

            });
        }
});
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your support. This one doesn't work so I change process bar model. 
http://jqueryrain.com/tutorial/progress-bar/demo46/

How can i add waypoint to this model?

Answer (score 1):

Try to use below code:

```
 function animateProgressBar(){
$(".skillbar > span").each(function() {
    $(this)
        .data("origWidth", $(this).width())
        .width(0)
        .animate({
            width: $(this).data("origWidth")
        }, 1200);
});
}

var waypoint = new Waypoint({
  element: document.getElementById('containerId'),
  handler: function(direction) {
    animateProgressBar();
  }
});
```